# How to add ALL components into Visual studio 2010's toolbox for WPF apps?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, toolbox

This is driving me crazy. I right clicked on the toolbox and selected all the components under WPF components tab and there are still components missing, such as LinearGradientBrush, RadialGradientBrush etc. Where are the missing components and where can I find their dlls?

Comment: Hopefully you did not actually find a brush back in that dialog, that would be rather bad.  Only components that you can drop on a window should be there of course.

Answer (score 0):

This ain't a direct answer to your question but maybe this might help you : Why are you not writing them directly in the XAML rather than using the designer? You'll eventually end up having to write the attributes of it anyway

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to see a list of all available properties and attributes? There are so many of them.

Comment: Maybe it's just my way but it's easier for me to remember them all, and when I don't know what I'm looking for I just google the existing controls